# 'Bad value' when trying to access a different sheet via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried writing a function that will change some values on a sheet that isn't the main sheet. I've tried both `openById` and `openByUrl`, and neither have worked correctly (the first commented line is the other solution I've tried):

```
function setRandomCode() {
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BOidZnEgdZhtkB8pAlYMBL6X-Ax3y46jVtli-LPhg0Y/edit#gid=524085816');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('524085816')
  var range = sheet.getRange('C3:F3');

  for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
    var codeValue = Math.round(Math.random()*5, 1);
    var beadColour;
    switch (codeValue)
    {
      case 0:
        beadColour = "Blue";
        break;
      case 1:
        beadColour = "Green";
        break;
      case 2:
        beadColour = "Red";
        break;
      case 3:
        beadColour = "Magenta";
        break;
      case 4:
        beadColour = "Cyan";
        break;
      case 5:
        beadColour = "Yellow";  
        break;      
    }
    range.getCell(1, x).setValue(beadColour);
  }  
}
```

When I try openById, it returns a 'Bad value' error. I've taken what I thought was the ID for the sheet from the URL.

When I try openByUrl, it executes the function correctly, but on the main sheet, not the sheet I want to change.

Is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using open by URL `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);`

You are getting the entire spreadsheet and its sheets as an object.

If you want to use `.getRange();` on a specific sheet then you can use `sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');` to get the sheet first and then call `.getRange();` on that object.

`SpreadsheetApp.openById('524085816')` This ID you have supplied here is the sheet ID for an individual sheet within a spreadsheet. You need to supply the actual spreadsheet ID in this call, so in your case that would be;

`SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BOidZnEgdZhtkB8pAlYMBL6X-Ax3y46jVtli-LPhg0Y');`

The Spreadsheet ID is the portion of the URL  between `/d/` and `/edit` in the URL

You can try the code below by modifying the ID and sheet name as necessary.

```
function setRandomCode() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BOidZnEgdZhtkB8pAlYMBL6X-Ax3y46jVtli-LPhg0Y');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
    var range = sheet.getRange('C3:F3');

    for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
        var codeValue = Math.round(Math.random() * 5, 1);
        var beadColour;
        switch (codeValue) {
        case 0:
            beadColour = "Blue";
            break;
        case 1:
            beadColour = "Green";
            break;
        case 2:
            beadColour = "Red";
            break;
        case 3:
            beadColour = "Magenta";
            break;
        case 4:
            beadColour = "Cyan";
            break;
        case 5:
            beadColour = "Yellow";
            break;
        }
        range.getCell(1, x).setValue(beadColour);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### When I try openById, it returns a 'Bad value' error.

The Spreadsheet Id has usually 44 characters - numbers and letters. It is the part of the URL that starts after `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/` and ends before `/edit`

When I try openByUrl, it executes the function correctly, but on the main sheet, not the sheet I want to change.

- `SpreadsheetApp.openById` and `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl` [open a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl), not a sheet.
- To address a sheet, you need to add e.g. [`getSheetByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Sample:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('PASTE HERE THE URL').getSheetByName('PASTE HERE THE NAME OF THE SHEET');
```